# Create A View For A One To Many Relation

Tags: sql-server

I have A Table Like This

```
a(Id,Code,Title)
```

And Another Table Like This

```
b(M,T1,T2,T3)
```

That Are Fk For Id In a

I Want To Have A Table Like This

```
c(b.M,a.Code,b.T1,a.Code,b.T2,a.Code,b.T3,a.Code)
```

How Can In Create A View For This.

Comment: Could you try to be a little more clear?

Comment: Wihch field is the foreign key? M?

Answer (score 2):

OK, lets assume that in table b M, T1, T2 and T3 are foregin keys to table a
(deduced from your expectation of c(b.M,a.Code,b.T1,a.Code,b.T2,a.Code,b.T3,a.Code))

You can try something like

```
SELECT  b.M,
        a.Code,
        b.T1,
        a1.Code,
        b.T2,
        a2.Code,
        b.T3,
        a3.Code
FROM    b LEFT JOIN
        a a ON  b.M = a.Id LEFT JOIN
        a a1    ON  b.T1 = a1.Id LEFT JOIN
        a a2    ON  b.T2 = a2.Id LEFT JOIN
        a a3    ON  b.T3 = a3.Id
```